# Create object from label and input - javascript, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to create an object with key value pairs that I will store to local storage. The markup looks like this:

```
<table id="equipmentTable" class="table">
 <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Category</th>
  <th class="thCenter">Quantity</th>
</tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
<tr>
  <td><label for="equipCatagory">Equipment1</label></td>
  <td><input type="email" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="0"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><label for="equipCatagory">Equipment2</label></td>
  <td><input type="email" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="0"></td>
</tr>
 <tr>
  <td><label for="equipCatagory">Equipment4</label></td>
  <td><input type="email" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="0"></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

The table rows get populated from a json object. I would like an object  with key value pairs of label:input that looks like this:

```
{
  fields:
   {
      Equipment1: 'quantity',
      Equipment2: 'quantity',
      Equipment3: 'quantity'
   }
}
```

What is the best approach to do this?

Comment: The best approach is JavaScript. Got any to show us?

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique. Javascript will still operate on multiple elements with the same id, but it's better to use a class for that.

Comment: Are you wanting to retrieve or set values?

Comment: Total oversight on the ID - whoops. I'm looking to retrieve and set values to an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var tableData = {};

$('.table tbody tr').each(function(){
    var label = $(this).find('label').text();
    var inputValue = $(this).find('input').val();
    tableData[label] = inputValue;
});
```

That said, you probably want to make those ID's unique on the form inputs.

Comment: This looks like it's almost what i need. This is returning an object for each row. How can I combine them all into one object?

Comment: Are you logging out tableData?

Comment: Yes, I am doing console.log(tableData) within the .each function.

Comment: You want to log it afterwards. When you are inside the loop, the object is still building. Stick it afterwards and you will see the full object result. That said, keys are unique, so if you have the same labels, it's going to overwrite the value on the last one.

Comment: I tried it both inside and out and figured inside was wrong. The issue was that on my local code the keys were indeed unique (copy and past dummy data) so it was overwriting it. That is not a situation I would run into so this works perfectly! thank you!